# enviar datos del datatable a un evento onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

he estado haciendo llamas mediante fetch api para poblar mis tablas, pero ahora quiero usar datatables, no he encontrado la manera de enviar el valor de la fila que quiero editar a mi evento onclick

este es mi codigo donde relleno mi tabla con los datos:

```
        function listaPersonas() {


                $("#tbPersona").DataTable({
                    "responsive": true,
                    "ajax": {
                        "url": "@Url.Action("Lista","Persona")",
                        "type": "GET",
                        "datatype": "json"
                    },
                    "columns": [
                        { "data": "identificacion" },
                        { "data": "nombre" },
                        { "data": "telefono" },
                        {
                            "data": null,
                            "className": "btn-editar",
                            "defaultContent": "<button >Edit</button>"
                        },

                    ]

                });

    }
```

Este es el evento onclick que tenía con la llamada fetch al que quiero enviar el valor de las columnas para mostrar un modal para la edición (antes todo se almacenaba en esta linea " let persona= $(this).data("modelo")" y la enviaba a la funcion mostrarmodal)

```
        $("#tbPersona tbody").on("click", ".btn-editar", function () {

        let persona = $(this).data("modelo")

        mostrarModal(persona)
    })
```

alguien podria ayudarme a orientarme como hacer lo mismo con el valor de las columnas del datatable, es la primera vez que trabajo con ellos y por ahi lei algo sobre el render pero no he logrado que el evento de editar le lleguen las variables de la fila seleccionada

Comment: Si lo que quieres es obtener valores de los <td> de una fila, entonces dentro de la funcion que le pasas al metodo on, tienes que obtener la fila primero con const tr = $(this).closest('tr')

Comment: Y despues acceder a la columna específica para obtener el dato que requieras con tr.find('td:eq(0)')

Comment: Siendo el 0 la primera columna

Comment: Prueba colocando el código const tr = $(this).closest('tr')  arriba de let persona = $(this).data("modelo")

Comment: Haz console.log despues,  console.log(tr.find('td:eq(0)'))

Comment: Eso que expliqué es para obtener datos de los td de un tr, el tr es segun que boton editar presiones

Comment: hola @ClintonTapiaLagar, gracias por tomarte el tiempo para contestar, publique una respuesta acerca de como lo resolví, te agradezco mucho si le puedes dar un ojo y decirme si es correcto de la forma que lo resolví.

Answer (score 0):

lo resolví de la siguiente manera aunque no se si sea lo más optimo:

```
        function listaPersonas() {
        $("#tbPersona").DataTable({
            "responsive": true,
            "ajax": {
                "url": "@Url.Action("Lista","Persona")",
                "type": "GET",
                "datatype": "json"
            },
            "columns": [
                { "data": "identificacion" },
                { "data": "nombre" },
                { "data": "telefono" },
                {
                    "data": null,
                    "render": function (data, type, row) {
                        return "<button class='btn btn-primary btn-editar' data-id='" + data.identificacion + "' data-nombre='" + data.nombre + "' data-telefono='" + data.telefono + "'>Editar</button>";
                    }
                },

            ]

        });

    }
```

y en la funcion on hice lo siguiente:

```
    $("#tbPersona tbody").on("click", ".btn-editar", function () {

        let NuevoModelo = Modelo_base;
        NuevoModelo["identificacion"] = $(this).data("id");
        NuevoModelo["nombre"] = $(this).data("nombre");
        NuevoModelo["telefono"] = $(this).data("telefono");

        mostrarModal(NuevoModelo)
    })
```